# where is text highlighted stored?

Tags: java, clipboard

I need to make an application which copies the highlighted text .

I tried this program

```
String myString = "This text will be copied into clipboard when running this code!";
StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection (myString);
Clipboard clpbrd = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ().getSystemClipboard ();
clpbrd.setContents (stringSelection, null);
```

but this copies the text already existing in clipboard
it prints the text from clipboard after we highlight the text and hit copy option

I want to know after we simply select a text by highlighting, where is this stored, how can I access this highlighted text directly without physically copying it by OS's copy option

Comment: I copied your code literally into Eclipse and after running it, the clipboard contained your string. Isn't that what you intended to achieve?

Comment: yeah it is supposed to do that , but my question is , i dont want to use copy option , i wan the text to go into clipboard after i just highlight the text

Comment: So catch an event that is fired when text is selected.

Comment: yeah exactly that  i want to know , which event is that , i tried to find but could not

Comment: i dont want to keep the application limited to my app only , i wanna find the option where whenever a text is highlighted , i may be able to access it , if only it is possible ofcourse , but my guess is the OS somewhere stores highlighted text then only we are able to copy it after using COPY option , i thought accessing clipboard will be enough but apparently it is not

Comment: There is no universal OS-wide mechanism for storing selected text, especially not within a Swing application, which doesn't even use such high-level native GUI services. The OS sees text selected in a Swing application as just some pixels.

Comment: I am not really aware of anything such so I m gonna go with your explanation , but the only doubt I have , when we select a text by highlighting , it might be stored somewhere , otherwise the copy option would not be able to copy the content , I dont need any universal OS solution , my need is limited to windows , so if there is any help regarding that ??

Comment: No the highlighted text itself is not stored anywhere. There's only the full text of the Swing component + start/end marks.

Comment: Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getSelectedText%28%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to selection changes using the [`CaretListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/caretlistener.html). Then you can retrieve the selected Text using the [`#getSelectedText()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getSelectedText%28%29).

Here is a simple example with a `TextArea`:

```java
    final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.addCaretListener(new CaretListener() {
        @Override
        public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {
            String selectedText = textArea.getSelectedText();
            // do something with it...
        }
    });
```

Comment: OP wants to be informed **globally** whenever, wherever text is selected.